# Перезапуск ядра TensorFlow из скрипта python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, нейронные-сети, keras, tensorflow

Могу ли я перезапустить ядро Tensorflow, не покидая python? Я пытаюсь обучать модель в каждом цикле с нуля. Вот мой вывод. Можно заметить, что на второй и последующих итерациях при закрытии tensorflow сессии  и инициализации новой, ядро не перезапускается.

```
FIRST ITERATION
2018-10-08 10:26:56.648784: I 
T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\platform\
cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this 
TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
2018-10-08 10:26:57.532765: I 
T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_ru
ntime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1405] Found device 0 with properties:
name: GeForce 840M major: 5 minor: 0 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.124
pciBusID: 0000:04:00.0
totalMemory: 2.00GiB freeMemory: 1.92GiB
2018-10-08 10:26:57.542119: I 
T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_ru
ntime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1484] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2018-10-08 10:26:58.513561: I 
T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_ru
ntime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:965] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with 
strength 1
edge matrix:
2018-10-08 10:26:58.520111: I 
T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_ru
ntime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:971]      0
2018-10-08 10:26:58.523109: I 
T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_ru
ntime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:984] 0:   N
2018-10-08 10:26:58.526154: I 
T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_ru
ntime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1097] Created TensorFlow device 
(/job:localhost/replica:
0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 1680 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: 
GeForce 840M, pci bus id: 0000:04:00.0, compute capability: 5.0)
Using TensorFlow backend.
~RUN MY MODEL~

SECOND ITERATION
2018-10-08 10:27:07.878636: I 
T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_ru
ntime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1484] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2018-10-08 10:27:07.885267: I 
T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_ru
ntime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:965] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with 
strength 1
edge matrix:
2018-10-08 10:27:07.890555: I 
T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_ru
ntime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:971]      0
2018-10-08 10:27:07.894000: I 
T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_ru
ntime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:984] 0:   N
2018-10-08 10:27:07.897367: I 
T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_ru
ntime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1097] Created TensorFlow device 
(/job:localhost/replica:
0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 1680 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: 
GeForce 840M, pci bus id: 0000:04:00.0, compute capability: 5.0)
~RUN MY MODEL~

ETC
```

Comment: а зачем перезапускать ядро?

Comment: Ожидаемый вопрос, попробую объяснить.У меня плохообучаемая сеть, при каждом запуске скрипта выход варируется. Задался целью усреднить результат. Так вот, в рамках одной инциализации ядра, как ни крути цикл, результат одинаковый. Но стоит перезапустить скрипт, появляются изменения.

Comment: [память очищать пробовали?](http://forums.fast.ai/t/tip-clear-tensorflow-gpu-memory/1979)

Comment: Не помогло, к сожалению.

Comment: Вопрос снят, небольшой мутации подвергались входные данные, поэтому и выход отличался.